# Length of a parametric curve define by equations $x = t - 1$ and $y=\sqrt{t}$

Tags: calculus, parametric

I was solving the following problem:

[image: Parametric equation problem]

After using the formula $$\text{length} = \int_b^a \sqrt{(x'(t))^2 + (y'(t))^2}\,dt,$$ I got $$\int_0^4 \sqrt{(1)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2}\,dt = \int_0^4 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}t^{-1}}\,dt \approx 4.646,$$

which is not one of the answer choices. Can anyone show me my mistake?

I also checked the solution to this problem and it seems that they did not take the derivative as in the formula above:

[image: Parametric equation solution]

Is there a reason why the problem was solved in this way? Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are right (I find $4.6467837624327...$) and the given "solution" is false !

Comment: They forgot to take the derivative! Is this from a book?

Comment: @MathLover. This is much more than a typo !!